# Difference between bookmark levels greater than one - what does this mean?

Tags: hyperref, warnings, bookmarks

When compiling my LaTeX file, I received this warning message.
Though I got the PDF file, I still want to know why this warning comes and how to fix it.

It occurs in this line.

```
\paragraph{Plane stress} Plane state of stress, a.k.a. plane stress, is a state of stress in which\[\sigma_{33}=\sigma_{31}=\sigma_{32}=0.\]
```

---

```
Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater(hyperref) than one,
level fixed on input line 97. Difference (2) between bookmark levels
is greater(hyperref) than one, level fixed.
```

The question may be seemed dummy to some TeX experts, but as a newbie here, I really don't know how it comes.

I attempt to write two subsubsections, but without numbering them. So I choose the command `\paragraph`. Is there any work-arounds?

Comment: I'm guessing you made a paragraph division without making a subsection first? `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection`, `\paragraph`, `\subparagraph` -- [Reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Sectioning_Commands)

Comment: Perhaps you have a `\paragraph` *without* a `\subsubsection`; only a `\subsection`. Since the PDF bookmarks tend to show a hierarchy, they follow the sectional depths via a structured indentation. Without all the proper in-between sectional structures, the bookmarks have to be "fixed" for the missing levels. That's just a guess, since I don't have an MWE to play with.

Comment: @Werner you are right. But I don't want to use \subsubsection. It makes the structure to cumbersome.

Comment: And if you're using `\paragraph` as a shorthand for "give me a block of text with a run-in header instead of a displayed one", then perhaps using [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) to redefine `\subsubsection` that way would be a solution.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This happens when you skip a level in the sectioning commands while still requesting to maintain an equivalent bookmark hierarchy. The following MWE reproduces the problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen]{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}% Show up to level 4 (\paragraph) in ToC (and bookmarks)
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\subparagraph{A subparagraph}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
%\subsubsection{A subsubsection}% Left out \subsubsection
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\subparagraph{A subparagraph}
\end{document}
```

Note how the second `\paragraph` is at the same level as the preceding `\subsubsection` level.

To circumvent this warning, don't skip elements of the sectional hierarchy. Rather redefine them to suit your formatting needs. Specific to your example, using `\subsubsection*` (the starred variant of `\subsubsection`) would leave the titles unnumbered - similar to that of `\paragraph`. However, there are other ways (either manually, or via a package like [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), say).

Alternatively, loading the [`bookmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) overrides this warning.

Comment: You could also circumvent this situation by setting `tocdepth` to a value lower than `4`, e. g., `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}`.  This will prevent paragraphs from showing up in the list of bookmarks and, thus, will also make the warnings go away.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is very good, but to put this in less practical and more philisophical terms, this issue is common when using `\paragraph` within a `\section` or `\subsection`. The fundamental issue is that wanting a themed paragraph is not really dependent on the section structure, so it makes sense to have a `\paragraph` in a section with no subsections. In contrast, subsections are explicitly semantically dependent on sections so they are mostly not affected by this problem. Therefore, filling out the hierarchy with unnecessary subsubsections or promoting the `\paragraph` to a `\subsubsection` (or worse, to a `\subsection`) may not be good solutions. Accepting that the ToC will be inconsistently indented is a possibility, but not a solution.

@ilpssun has mentioned this in a comment to the accepted answer, but I feel this deserves more visibility:

It may be preferable to simply exclude `\paragraph`s from the ToC. For this, `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` somewhere before `\tableofcontents` will add only chapters, sections subsections, and subsubsections to the ToC. `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` will remove subsubsections, etc.