# Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater than one

Tags: sectioning

I have Similar Question to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52576/difference-between-bookmark-levels-greater-than-one-what-does-this-mean) .
I have following hierarchy

> \part -> \section -> more than one \subsection --> the content of
>   subsection .
>   see the following code

```
necessary imports are here (assume it)
.
\begin{document}
\title{THE TITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents{}
\part{PART1}
\section{SECTION1}
\subsection{SUBSECTION1.1}
 fmksmnd
 nsdjkn
 nvkdfjnv
 \subsection{SUBSECTION1.2} 
  dsmvndsmv
  n v,mvn f
  nsdv,sdn
 \part{PART2}
  SAME STRUCTURE TILL THE END 
 \end{document}
```

And I am getting the same warning !

Comment: Have you read the accepted answer? This work or not? If not what happend?

Comment: Yes I read it . according to that everything is fine . section ->subsection -> content/paragraphs but not sure about \Part ..

Comment: If you read the post, you can see that warning is coming because of the skip of one level. In this case it's `\chapter`. Why don't put it instead of `\part`? Eventually you can redefine `\chapter` to have the same style as `\part`

Comment: This happens if you use the `report` class, which needs `\chapter` between `\part` and `\section`. If you don't have chapters, use the `article` class.

Comment: Yeah @egreg you are correct just fixed it . ! another solution is use `\usepackage{bookmark}` with report class.

Comment: So problem is the same as the other post you linked (use `\usepackage{bookmark}`): possible duplication