# Don't fix differences in bookmark level greater than one

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I sometimes get `Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater (hyperref) than one, level fixed` (see [Difference between bookmark levels greater than one - what does this mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52576)).

How do I stop `hyperref` from fixing this? Sometimes I can have a `\subsubsection` under a `\section`. I don't want the `\subsubsection` bookmarked as a `\subsection`.

Comment: Please post a small example which can be used to reproduce the message. I don't remember ever seeing this (though I see plenty of other messages from `hyperref`).

Comment: you shouldn't have a subsubsection under a section, that's just wrong:-) LaTeX is reasonably forgiving and lets you omit levels but the way bookmarks work in pdf that's not really possible, and in order to create a valid pdf file hyperef has to fake a section level to make the bookmark structure correct. but Werner's answer in the referenced question suggests the `bookmark` package avoids this warning, did you try that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, so it is a constraint imposed by the PDF format?

Comment: well the folding tree UI in the bookmark pane doesn't really allow a level to be skipped, so either you need to promote the subsubsections up a level in the bookmarks or add the missing subsection with a blank title in the bookmarks, so hyperref has to do something, but basically the input is wrong, so it is error recovery.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That answers my question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I think, you should write the answer ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you please write ananswer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't have a subsubsection under a section. LaTeX is reasonably forgiving and lets you omit levels but the way bookmarks work in pdf that's not really possible, and in order to create a valid pdf file hyperref has to fake a section level to make the bookmark structure correct. Werner's answer in the referenced question suggests the bookmark package avoids this warning.

The folding tree design in the bookmark pane doesn't really allow a level to be skipped, so either you need to promote the subsubsections up a level in the bookmarks or add the missing subsection with a blank title in the bookmarks, so hyperref has to do something, but basically the input is wrong, so it is error recovery.