# Wrapping text in a fixed width table so that table height adjusts

Tags: tables, multirow, wrap, tabulary

I looked at these questions but they didn't seem to solve my issue because using a `parbox` for the first column cell doesn't make the table adjust to the content in the first cell, nor does simply specifying the `cm` width within the `multirow` option.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[]{multirow}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}% This is for quotes
\usepackage{tabulary}% This is for tables
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e}% This is formatting for long tables
% \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}%This is a wrapper to make everything a certain width - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx}% This is for images
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,caption}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}%This is for precision tables per property
% \captionsetup{labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false} % optional, this makes the caption numbers appear on a new line.
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}} % "decimal" column type
\renewcommand{\ast}{{}^{\textstyle *}} % for raised "asterisks"
\usepackage{bookmark}% This overrides warnings like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52576/difference-between-bookmark-levels-greater-than-one-what-does-this-mean
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}| }
\hline
\textbf{Sentence} & \textbf{Training Examples} & \textbf{Region} & \textbf{Value} \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{3.25cm}{"Countries with higher GDP per capita at the lower end of the scale include Azerbaijan (around \$7,500) and Botswana (around \$8,900) and as we head up the scale we find South Korea (around \$27,500),the United Kingdom (\$39,600), the United States (\$48,150) and right at the top we find Qatar (\$98,000) and Luxembourg (\$ 122,147)."} & LB & Lucus Radebe & Bla \\
 & DC & Michael Duberry & Bla \\
 & DC & Dominic Matteo & Bla \\
 & RB & Didier Domi  & Bla\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\savebox` can be really useful in many examples, although sometimes they might be a bit hacky.

This works in the way that it is saving a parbox set to the specified width into a box. We can then calculate the height of that box using `\totalheightof{}` from `calc`-package. Then we distribute this length for every row, 4 rows would equal 25% of the height of the box. We then use this length for the linelinespecifier `\\[\spacing]`, but this would overshoot a bit. How much? Well, LaTeX has first added a line in the table, and aftwerwards inserts this length of black space, so we need to take that into account. Therefore, we change the length to `\setlength{\customSpacing}{.25\sentenceHeight-\baselineskip}`

#### Further suggestions:

- Putiting this much text in a table is not very convinient for your reader. Consider putting that text in a a paragraph for itself, possibly in a caption, or notes below the table.

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[]{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}%
\usepackage{calc}

\newcolumntype{W}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

  \newsavebox{\sentence}
  \savebox{\sentence}{\parbox{3.25cm}{\RaggedRight``Countries with higher GDP per capita at the lower end of the scale include Azerbaijan (around \$7,500) and Botswana (around \$8,900) and as we head up the scale we find South Korea (around \$27,500),the United Kingdom (\$39,600), the United States (\$48,150) and right at the top we find Qatar (\$98,000) and Luxembourg (\$122,147).''}}
  \newlength{\sentenceHeight}
  \setlength{\sentenceHeight}{\totalheightof{\usebox{\sentence}}}

  \begin{table}[!ht]
    \newcommand{\headerFormat}[1]{% Define a headerformat, only used in this specific table.
  \multicolumn{1}{|m{3.25cm}|}{\centering\bfseries#1}
}
    \newlength{\customSpacing}
    \setlength{\customSpacing}{.25\sentenceHeight-\baselineskip}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ *{4}{|W{3.25cm}}| }
      \hline
      \headerFormat{Sentence} & \headerFormat{Training\par Examples} & \headerFormat{Region} & \headerFormat{Value} \\
      \hline
      \multirow{4}{*}{\usebox{\sentence}} & LB & Lucus Radebe & Bla \\[\customSpacing]
      & DC & Michael Duberry & Bla \\[\customSpacing]
      & DC & Dominic Matteo & Bla \\[\customSpacing]
      & RB & Didier Domi  & Bla\\[\customSpacing]
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: this is a great answer and makes sense, however I am getting that `\spacing` is already defined - perhaps because of conflict with another package I might have loaded?

Comment: Yes, just rename it.

Comment: Also, I took your advice on changing the table so easier to read - I now have a `multicolumn` sentence column as the second column so I only have two columns overall, and the entity/value appear below the sentence in the second column. See ``\small
\begin{longtable}{@{}|C{5cm}|C{4cm}|C{4cm}|@{}}
\hline
\textbf{Sentence} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}C{8cm}|}{\textbf{Training Examples}}\\ 
\toprule
\multirow{4}{5cm}{"bla"} 
& 
\multicolumn{2}{@{}C{8cm}}{"bla"}\\\cline{2-3}
 & Radebe & Bla  \\\cline{2-3}
\end{longtable} 
\normalsize``

Comment: I tried your method, renaming `\spacing` to `\customspacing` but I get this effect: http://prnt.sc/cegnz1

Comment: @DhruvGhulati Have a look at the column-specifier. I changed it into using `p` instead of `m` for the C-column. You could ofcourse create a new column instead and use that.

Comment: My bad. Thesis angst. Thank you so much for your help @Runar!

Comment: I have adapted your table and its looking amazing. Thank you! How do I make the first cell in the first column (the multi row) middle aligned vertically? it currently is top aligned if you add more data.

Comment: @DhruvGhulati I made the edits into the post. Basically, use a multirow, but I set up a macro for the headerformat here, so yu do have to type so much redundant information. I also removed everything not related, and cleaned it up a bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44963/discussion-between-dhruv-ghulati-and-runar-trollet).

Answer (score 5):

You can solve your problem in two ways:

- With `multirow`, count the number of `lines` required ((not `rows`!) and add to the 2nd column a supplementary cell with invisible rule of the required depth (found by trial and errors)
- `without multirow, make, from the 2nd row, the 2nd to 4th columns a nested tabular inserted in a`\multicolumn`.

In both cases I based the definition of `L,C,R` columntypes on `p{…}` type, as I supposed the `m{…}`type was used to have column heads vertically centred, which I obtain with the `\thead` command, from `makecell`.

**Added:**: I also propose a third solution so that rows 2-5 in columns 2-4 be equally spaced.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage{xcolor} %
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}% This is for quotes
    \usepackage{tabulary}% This is for tables
    \usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e}% This is formatting for long tables
    % \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}%This is a wrapper to make everything a certain width - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \usepackage{graphicx}% This is for images
    \usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,caption, makecell}
    \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}%This is for precision tables per property
    % \captionsetup{labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false} % optional, this makes the caption numbers appear on a new line.
    \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}} % "decimal" column type
    \renewcommand{\ast}{{}^{\textstyle *}} % for raised "asterisks"
    \usepackage{bookmark}% This overrides warnings like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52576/difference-between-bookmark-levels-greater-than-one-what-does-this-mean
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}| }
    \hline
    \thead{Sentence} & \thead{Training\\ Examples} & \thead{Region} & \thead{Value} \\ \hline
    \multirow{17}{3.25cm}{"Countries with higher GDP per capita at the lower end of the scale include Azerbaijan (around \$\,7,500) and Botswana (around \$\,8,900) and as we head up the scale we find South Korea (around \$\,27,500),the United Kingdom (\$\,39,600), the United States (\$48,150) and right at the top we find Qatar (\$\,98,000) and Luxembourg (\$\,122,147)."}%
     & LB & Lucus Radebe & Bla \rule{0pt}{2.5ex}\\
     & DC & Michael Duberry & Bla \\
     & DC & Dominic Matteo & Bla \\
     & RB & Didier Domi & Bla \\%
      & \rule[-18.5\baselineskip] {0pt}{0pt} & & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[!hb]
    \centering%
    \begin{tabular}{ |C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}|}
    \hline
    \thead{Sentence} & \thead{Training\\ Examples} & \thead{Region} & \thead{Value}
    \\ \hline
   \rule{0pt}{2.5ex} {"Countries with higher GDP per capita at the lower end of the scale include Azerbaijan (around \$\,7,500) and Botswana (around \$\,8,900) and as we head up the scale we find South Korea (around \$\,27,500),the United Kingdom (\$\,39,600), the United States (\$\,48,150) and right at the top we find Qatar (\$\,98,000) and Luxembourg (\$\,122,147)."}
     &
     \multicolumn{3}{@{}c|}{\begin{tabular}[t] {C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}}
     \rule{0pt}{2.5ex}LB & Lucus Radebe & Bla \\
      DC & Michael Duberry & Bla \\
     DC & Dominic Matteo & Bla \\
     RB & Didier Domi & Bla \\[18.2\baselineskip] & & \end{tabular}}%%
    \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \clearpage

    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering%
    \begin{tabular}{ |C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}|}
    \hline
    \thead{Sentence} & \thead{Training\\ Examples} & \thead{Region} & \thead{Value}
    \\ \hline
  \multirow{17}{\linewidth}{"Countries with higher GDP per capita at the lower end of the scale include Azerbaijan (around \$\,7,500) and Botswana (around \$\,8,900) and as we head up the scale we find South Korea (around \$\,27,500),the United Kingdom (\$\,39,600), the United States (\$\,48,150) and right at the top we find Qatar (\$\,98,000) and Luxembourg (\$\,122,147)."}
     & \rule{0pt}{2.5ex}LB & Lucus Radebe & Bla\\ %
     & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c|}{\setlength\extrarowheight{92pt}\begin{tabular}[t] {C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}|C{3.25cm}}%
      DC & Michael Duberry & Bla \\%
     DC & Dominic Matteo & Bla \\%
     RB & Didier Domi & Bla %
     \end{tabular}}%
    \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

     \end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: this doesn't seem to do what i need as the other rows are not matching up to fit the first column in terms of vertical distribution.

Comment: @Dhruv Gulati: If I've well understood what you mean, this is due to the use of `\extrarowheight` and `\makegapedcells` to give some vertical padding to cells. I've modified my code to retain the padding without the side effect. Is it like you want now?

Comment: See @RunarTrollets answer - the issue is that the rest of the cells from columns 2-4 are not distributed evenly vertically spaced through the columns, unlike what he does.

Comment: @Dhruv Gulati: I didn't even try to obtain such a result. I didn't understand it's what you want.

Comment: @Dhruv Gulati: I added a third solution that fulfills your requirements (hope I've well understood now…)

Comment: @Runar Trollet: That wouldn't be the first time it happens, but, in addition to the double `\end{document}`, which is innocuous, is there anything else?

Comment: @Runar Trollet: Oh! yes. When I made my addition, I thought I had copied only the third code. I've fixed that. Many thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, such a multirow works out of the box with ConTeXt Natural Tables; no trickery required:

```
\startsetups table:style
\setupTABLE[each][each][frame=off,leftframe=on, rightframe=on]
\setupTABLE[row][first][style=bold, align={middle,lohi}, topframe=on, bottomframe=on]
\setupTABLE[row][last] [bottomframe=on]
\setupTABLE[each][each][align=middle, width=3.25cm]
\stopsetups

\starttext
\startTEXpage[offset=2mm]
\startTABLE[setups={table:style}]
  \NC Sentence \NC Training Examples \NC Region \NC Value \NC \NR
  \NC[nr=4, align=flushleft, bottomframe=on]
     “Countries with higher GDP per capita at the lower end of the scale include Azerbaijan (around \$7,500) and Botswana (around \$8,900) and as we head up the scale we find South Korea (around \$27,500),the United Kingdom (\$39,600), the United States (\$48,150) and right at the top we find Qatar (\$98,000) and Luxembourg (\$122,147).”
  \NC LB \NC Lucus Radebe    \NC Bla \NC \NR
  \NC DB \NC Michael Duberry \NC Bla \NC \NR
  \NC DB \NC Dominic Matteo  \NC Bla \NC \NR
  \NC RB \NC Didier Domi     \NC Bla \NC \NR
\stopTABLE
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

[image]