# Can't locate input line for an error

Tags: errors, hyperref, warnings, line, find

I'm trying to debug my thesis and found this warning in the error log:

> Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater (hyperref) than one, level fixed on input line 161.

This points towards my main file that only has 73 lines (comments included). I'm using the `\input`command to import the various chapters and files. I'm using TexMaker.

I found this thread [Difference between bookmark levels greater than one - what does this mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52576/difference-between-bookmark-levels-greater-than-one-what-does-this-mean) explaining the warning and how to solve it, but I can't manage to locate the problem because of this inconsistency in line numbering. Can anybody help?

Comment: Use the option `--file-line-error` when compiling then the log will also tell the file name.

Comment: the log file shows which file is involved, by showing `(foo.tex` when `foo.tex` is opened and `)` when it is closed so you can check matching `(...)` to see the file, or using the command line option Ulrike mentioned can be easier.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer actually not in this case, as it is a latex warning using `\linenumber` not an error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh yes, I shouldn't have concentrated so much on the title of the question. But it is still hot here  ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it's always hot in England so we are used to it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify the example in the linked question so it looks like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen]{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}% Show up to level 4 (\paragraph) in ToC (and bookmarks)
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\subparagraph{A subparagraph}
\input{sc2.tex}
\end{document}
```

where `sc2.tex` is

```
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
%\subsubsection{A subsubsection}% Left out \subsubsection
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\subparagraph{A subparagraph}
```

then the terminal and log shows the error as

```
(./main.out) (./main.out) (./sc2.tex

Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater 
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 5.
```

where `(main.out)` shows the file `main.out` has been read completely but `(./sc2.tex` with no matching `)` shows that that file is opened but not fully read, so the line number in any error or warning in that section relates to `sc2.tex`.

Comment: @SebastianoGenna answered questions are not closed (otherwise the answers would not be available to later readers), they can be "accepted" but only you can do that:-)